# Fill child DIV with content

Tags: javascript

is it possible to remove the **class="con"** from the DIV, handle it like a "child DIV" from **lis** and put the content into it?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="lis" id="123">Title...<div class="con"></div></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("lis"), function(elem) {
elem.addEventListener("click", function() {

 // get data via ajax

 this.getElementsByClassName("con")[0].innerHTML = data;

 });
})
</script>
```

So it should look like this:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="lis" id="123">Title...<div></div></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script>

[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByClassName("lis"), function(elem) {
elem.addEventListener("click", function() {

 // get data via ajax

 // put the data into the child of this.id / lis DIV

 });
})
</script>
```

Comment: You seem to be asking 3 separate questions. What's not working?

Comment: @isherwood It works atm but i want to save some bytes and so remove the "class=con" from the DIV.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript

Comment: `this.querySelector("div:first-child").innerHTML = data;`
even `this.querySelector("div").innerHTML = data` would work